NextJS: Functions in Server Actions vs Server Components
Is there a difference/advantage between defining an async function inside the server component and calling it within the SC or defining it in a server action?

Server actions are a POST request under the hood. This means that, whenever you define a server action, NextJS compiler puts your server action's code in a route handler (API) as POST and gives you a syntax sugar of the post request in the client, so you don't need to do await fetch("...", {method: "POST"}) but easily just do await myServerAction(...)
With that being said, the server actions are only the best option if you want to mutate some data in the backend from the client (That's what the POST requests are for)
And if you want to just get data and use in your component, you can directly get them in your server component or put them in a separate function to have a DRY code.
